# find . -size -1GB in Centos

Tags: find, size

In Centos, I have a text file in my home directory.

The command `find . -size -1M` doesn't show my file but `find . -size -1000k` does show it. This problem just seems to be happening when I use the number "1". The first command will work if I use `-2M` even though the file is only 500k in size.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: 1M == 1024k, not 1000k

Comment: Cheers, rookie mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`find . -size -1M` will only show file of size less than 1M, that is 0M. Yes, I know, it's confusing.

`find . -size 1M` will show you files whose size (rounded up to the upper MiB) is 1M (so any file size from 1 to 1048576). If you want from 0 to 1048575 (< 1M), that would be:

```
find . -size -1048576c
```

If you want from 0 to 1048576 (<= 1M)

```
find . -size -2M
```

or

```
find . ! -size +1M
```